# populate drop down from results using ajax

Tags: forms, ajax

I am having a problem trying to get ajax functioning properly, everytime I do a call i get

```
An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
HTTP Result Code: 500
Debugging information follows.
Path: /system/ajax
StatusText: Internal Server Error
ResponseText:
```

What am i trying to do is have the drop down fill with the results of a function from api. The function works perfectly it gets the results when needed however the problem is with the ajax I even try to print out hello world and still got the 500 error.

this is the code I currently have, any advice is appreciated.

```
function autotitleform($form, &$form_state){

    $form['vehicle_info'] = array(
        '#type' => ('fieldset'),
        '#title' => t('Vehicle Information'),
    );

    $form['autoinfo']['vehicle_year'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => t('Vehicle Year'),
        '#options' => auto_title_year_api(),
        '#ajax' => array(
            'callback' => 'auto_title_make_api_callback',
            'wrapper' => 'api_make'
        ),
    );

    $form['autoinfo']['wrapper'] = array(
        '#prefix' => '<div id="api_make">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
    );



    $options = array('- Select Make -');
    if(isset($form_state['values']['vehicle_year'])){
        $options = auto_title_make_api();
    }

    $form['autoinfo']['wrapper']['make_description'] = array(
        '#title' => t('City'),
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#options' => auto_title_make_api(),
  );    

    if(isset($form_state['values'])){
        $form['page_output'] = array(
        '#markup' => autotitledb_submit($form, $form_state)
        ); 
    }
    return $form;
}


function auto_title_make_api_callback($form, $form_state) {
  return $form['autoinfo']['wrapper'];
}

function auto_title_make_api(){
$url_make = 'https://test.api.800loanmart.com/Loanmartservice.svc/soapssl'; // SOAP 1.1 
$post_str_make = '<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body>
<GetVehicleMakes xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<customerId>73c858f0-791c-454e-b4d5-5634bf13621d</customerId>
<authenticationId>3074940f-7efe-447c-a7ff-3c152acdf8c4</authenticationId>
<year>2000</year>
</GetVehicleMakes>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>';

    $headers_make = array(
        'Content-type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"',                      // For SOAP 1.1 - JHW Jan 26, 2013
        "Accept: text/xml",
        "Cache-Control: no-cache",
        "Pragma: no-cache",
        "SOAPAction: \"http://tempuri.org/ILoanmartService/GetVehicleMakes\"",
        "Content-length: ".strlen($post_str_make)       // Amount of data in bytes to be posted
    );

      $options_make = array(
          CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,         // return web page / XML result
          CURLOPT_HEADER         => 0,          // 1/0 return/don't return headers 0 for production or 1 for debug
          CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => $headers_make,          // post headers
          CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,         // follow redirects
          CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",           // handle all encodings

          // Browser/User Agent String
          CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],     

          CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,         // set referer on redirect
          CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,          // timeout on connect
          CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,          // timeout on response
          CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,           // stop after 10 redirects
          CURLOPT_POST           => 1,            // We are sending post data needs to be = '1'
          CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $post_str_make,     // this is the XML post data
          CURLOPT_PORT           => 443,                    // SSL Port, probably unnesecery             

          CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,        // Don't verify ssl on either side
          CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,        // dito, don't verify ssl on either side

          CURLOPT_VERBOSE        => 1,            // Set to 1 for debug 
        );


    $soap_do_make = curl_init($url_make);
    curl_setopt_array($soap_do_make, $options_make);            
    $result_make = curl_exec($soap_do_make);


$sls_make = simplexml_load_string($result_make);
$sls_make->registerXPathNamespace('a', 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/LM.API');
$sls_list_make = $sls_make->xpath('//a:MakeDescription');
foreach($sls_list_make as $sls_list_make_child){

$sls_list_make_child_result[] = sprintf("%s", $sls_list_make_child);}
dpr($sls_list_make_child_result);
$sls_list_make_child_results = array_combine($sls_list_make_child_result, $sls_list_make_child_result);

        // Close cURL
        curl_close($soap_do_make);


 return $sls_list_make_child_results;
}
function auto_title_year_api(){
$url_year = 'https://test.api.800loanmart.com/Loanmartservice.svc/soapssl'; // SOAP 1.1   
$post_str_year = '<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body>
<GetVehicleYears xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<customerId>73c858f0-791c-454e-b4d5-5634bf13621d</customerId>
<authenticationId>3074940f-7efe-447c-a7ff-3c152acdf8c4</authenticationId>
</GetVehicleYears>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>';

    $headers_year = array(
        'Content-type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"',                      // For SOAP 1.1 - JHW Jan 26, 2013
        "Accept: text/xml",
        "Cache-Control: no-cache",
        "Pragma: no-cache",
        "SOAPAction: \"http://tempuri.org/ILoanmartService/GetVehicleYears\"",
        "Content-length: ".strlen($post_str_year)       // Amount of data in bytes to be posted
    );

      $options_year = array(
          CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,         // return web page / XML result
          CURLOPT_HEADER         => 0,          // 1/0 return/don't return headers 0 for production or 1 for debug
          CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => $headers_year,          // post headers
          CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,         // follow redirects
          CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",           // handle all encodings

          // Browser/User Agent String
          CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],     

          CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,         // set referer on redirect
          CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,          // timeout on connect
          CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,          // timeout on response
          CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,           // stop after 10 redirects
          CURLOPT_POST           => 1,            // We are sending post data needs to be = '1'
          CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $post_str_year,     // this is the XML post data
          CURLOPT_PORT           => 443,                    // SSL Port, probably unnesecery             

          CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,        // Don't verify ssl on either side
          CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,        // dito, don't verify ssl on either side

          CURLOPT_VERBOSE        => 1,            // Set to 1 for debug 
        );


    $soap_do_year = curl_init($url_year);
    curl_setopt_array($soap_do_year, $options_year);            
    $result_year = curl_exec($soap_do_year);


$sls_year = simplexml_load_string($result_year);
$sls_year->registerXPathNamespace('a', 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/LM.API');
$sls_list_year = $sls_year->xpath('//a:Year');
foreach($sls_list_year as $sls_list_year_child)
{$sls_list_year_child_result[] = sprintf("%s", $sls_list_year_child);}

$sls_list_year_child_results = array_combine($sls_list_year_child_result, $sls_list_year_child_result);

        // Close cURL
        curl_close($soap_do_year);


 return $sls_list_year_child_results;
}
```

Edit #1

```
The errors I am gettings are 
Notice: Undefined index: #options in form_select_options() (line 2661 of /home/loansdotorg/public_html/includes/form.inc).

And 

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in form_select_options() (line 2668 of /home/loansdotorg/public_html/includes/form.inc).
```

Edit #2 I think I have this working although I will need to test it out more.

Comment: What does your server log say?  Do you see a real error message if you browse directly to the AJAL URL?

Comment: I took a look at the report log and it isnt giving any errors back. I am clueless as to what the problem is, and as for going to the ajax url, do you mean site.com/system/ajax? Because if so I did go to that url and it was just a white screen. Any other suggestions?

Comment: If you are getting a 500 error, then the error should be in the apache error log.  The white screen is a 500 error too.  Check out http://drupal.org/node/158043 and report back.  My guess is either the cURL or the simplexml is barfing.

Comment: Actually I see i am gettings errors now, I must have missed them. I posted the error above in a edit

Comment: Neither of those should generate a 500.

Comment: What's the reason for these lines: `if(isset($form_state['values']['vehicle_year'])){
        $options = auto_title_make_api();
    }`? You're explicitly setting `'#options' => auto_title_make_api(),` immediately after...

Answer (score 1):

If you look at function "form_select_options()" it also sets the selected item so 
set `'#default' => 0` for your dropdown form variable and you wont see see that warning anymore!

```
$form['autoinfo']['vehicle_year'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => t('Vehicle Year'),
        '#options' => auto_title_year_api(),
        '#default' => 0, //this was missing and hence the warning, 
        '#ajax' => array(
            'callback' => 'auto_title_make_api_callback',
            'wrapper' => 'api_make'
        ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using devel module and dd() that return value just before the return to ensure it is correctly structured. with devel enabled a drupal_debug.txt file will be created on server in /tmp

Answer (score -1):

When I call a web service from php I do something like this:

```
  $client = new SoapClient("Your URL .svc?WSDL");
  $result = $client->MethodName(array('param' => 'value'));
  $result_object = $result->MethodNameResult;
```

Then you don't need to make the whole soap body and envelope. If you need to pass credentials in the header you can use:

```
$client = new SoapClient("some.wsdl", array('login'          => "some_name",
                                            'password'       => "some_password"));
```